# How to display CPU-Temperature in Wingpanel?

Tags: wingpanel, temperature, stats

Or other sensor values.

An iMac has also an Ambient Temperature Sensor for example. (what sensor is what?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several applications

### Power-Gadget indicator

Download the latest DEB from the [official downloadpage](https://bitbucket.org/baltic/power-gadget/downloads) and install it manually.

[image]

### PSensor

Psensor is avaible via elementary OS' repositories, to install it open a terminal session and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

[image]

### Sensors indicator

Add the following PPA to your sources or [download](https://launchpad.net/~alexmurray/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-sensors/+sourcepub/4472975/+listing-archive-extra) the DEB and install it manually:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sensors
```

[image]

### Syspeek indicator

Add the following PPA to your sources or [download](http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/s/syspeek/) the DEB and install it manually:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install syspeek
```

[image]

### indicator-cpufreq

indicator-cpufreq is avaible via elementary OS' repositories, to install it open a terminal session and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

[image]

You can find a list with sensor codes [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151103144947/http://www.parhelia.ch/blog/statics/k3_keys.html)

---

Don't forget to install the [elementary+ icon theme](https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus) to get all the indicator icons that resemble elementary OS' style.

Comment: is one of them able to display one or multiple values, like "75°C" in Wingpanel? i tried PSensor and it doesn't. https://i.imgur.com/TDHpRSV.png

Comment: @davidak try Sensors indicator

Comment: @davidak and don't forget to install the elementary+ icon theme

Comment: i can only display one value but that is ok. https://i.imgur.com/xP3Jlkc.png thanks!

Comment: Just installed `psensors`. Was able to add the temperature by going to the Sensor Preferences, and saying to display the temperature in the label (under Application Indicator)