# Is there a CPU/memory indicator for Pantheon?

Tags: wingpanel

I used the [System Monitor](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/90) spice for cinnamon when I was using Linux Mint. Is there some thing similar for Pantheon that I can use with elementary OS?

Comment: please refer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2963/is-there-a-task-manager-for-elementary-os-freya/2968?noredirect=1#comment5216_2968)

Comment: I think he means one that shows on wingpanel, in which case see these answers [1](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/40/how-can-i-show-performance-graphs-in-wingpanel),[2](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/611/how-to-display-cpu-temperature-in-wingpanel).